# Why is my Google Maps Marker not displaying?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-cloud-platform, google-maps-api-3

Why can't I add a marker to Google Maps on my page? I am working with Google Maps API. I don't know what the problem is. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>

    <script type="text/javascript"   src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API&callback=initMap" ></script>  
    </head>   
    <body>
 
 
    <div class="location"style="height: 300px; width: 600px;"></div>
   
    <script>
       let loc = document.querySelector(".location");
      window.onload=loadMap
       
     function loadMap(){
      const myLatLng = { lat: 50.488057309872424, lng: 30.47287431851951 };
      let options={
            center:myLatLng,
            zoom: 15,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      }
      let map=new google.maps.Map(loc,options)
      
    let marker= new google.maps.Marker({
      positon: myLatLng,  
      map:map,
      title: "Это ВЫ!"
     });
}           
    </script>      
  </body>
</html>
```

I read Google documentation but I can't find my mistake.

Comment: `window.onload=loadMap()` should be `window.onload=loadMap` - adding the `()` will fire the function immediately.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that allows to reproduce the issue. Where is your HTML? CSS? + your JS is incomplete.

Comment: @Professor Abronsius    oh,okay. im fix this, but my problem still here(

Comment: @MrUpsidown i update my questions and add html

Comment: Your `div` element is languishing somewhere in no-mans land. Any content element, such as a DIV should be in the body. Also, as you call `initMap` within the script uri you do not need to call it explicitly in `window.onload=initmap`

Comment: The reason, I believe, that your marker is **not** displaying is because of a typo. It should be `position` rather than `positon`

Comment: You should restrict your API key. Anyone can use it now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A corrected example that **will** display the marker once the correct apikey is used. The issue was the incorrect spelling of `position`... also removed the `window.onload=loadMap` as that was redundant if using the `callback` parameter in the script url. Adding `async` and `defer` to the script url should help ensure that the dom is loaded before attempting to run the javascript code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    .location {
      width: 600px;
      height: 300px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="location"></div>

  <script>
    function loadMap() {
      const myLatLng = {
        lat: 50.488057309872424,
        lng: 30.47287431851951
      };
      let options = {
        center: myLatLng,
        zoom: 15,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      }
      let map = new google.maps.Map(document.querySelector(".location"), options);

      let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        map: map,
        title: ""
      })
    }
  </script>
  <script async defer src='//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=loadMap'></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @MrUpsidown.. thanks for the SO apikey, did not know that existed!